# What is the standard way to use Python module os to specify the paths for third parties?

Tags: python, csv, path

(I'm not used to writing python programs for other users to use, so hopefully this question is appropriate.)

My users will download a file `generic_file.csv` and let's assume that this file will be saved in the "current directory".

So, I write a python script named `reader.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import (print_function, absolute_import)

import os
import csv
import random
import string

cd_path = os.getcwd() # return path of current directory
filename = 'generic_file.csv' # filename 'test_enigma.csv'
filepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename) # returns path to open fname

print(filepath)
```

Now, if the user runs this in the terminal with `python reader.py`, it should output the name of the file, ONLY IF the file was saved in the current directory.

That's inconvenient. Most users will just download the file, and they would like `reader.py` to change to the subdirectory `Downloads` and read `generic_file.csv` from that directory.

(1) How does one use `os.chdir()` to work for every user?

(2) What is the standard way to do this if I was writing third-party software? I imagine I would have the user download the specific CSV file and Python script together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to get the path name of User A's download file, you can do `os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads')`. This will return `/Users/A/Downloads`

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks!